# How to fix "Cannot resolve method 'getActionView()' " in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm currently learning how to set up a search interface in Android Studio following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#java). 
So far I've been following it to the best of my ability, but at [this step](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sc), I encountered a problem: "Cannot resolve method 'getActionView()'"

My MainActivity

```
package com.androiddeveloper.searchfunctionality;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search.getActionView());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My options_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title=".MainActivity/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

My searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <searchable xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label = "@string/app_name"
        android:hint = "@string/search_hint"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My ic_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</selector>
```

```
My Manifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androiddeveloper.searchfunctionality">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <activity>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name = ".SearchResultsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Filter the log for this application only and post it

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: In the logcat use the filter show only selected application log, also change the verbose to error

Comment: It comes up empty?

Comment: There seems to be nothing in the LogCat, but in the Build tab, :app:processDebugManifest and Execute taskAction come up red

Comment: Some error related to manifest file I think, check some articles for knowing errors from logcat

Comment: I did some digging and found out that there are merging errors in the manifest? It goes like this: Error: Missing 'name' key attribute on element activity at AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-26:16 app main manifest (this file), line 22 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Comment: Updated to include manifest.xml

Comment: `<activity>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>` remove the activity tags then it'll work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search.getActionView());
```

to

```
SearchView searchView =
        (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

You should use `findItem` for getting the item using id.

Comment: I did what you said and the "Cannot resolve method 'getActionView() " does go away, however when I run the code, I still get the log.

Comment: post your new log in the question

Comment: It is done, also what do you mean when you say I should use "findItem"?